# 405 error trying to DELETE request ajax - java

Tags: java, jquery, http-status-code-405, http-delete

i'm trying to make a delete request to my java service with a ajax request from my clientside. But when i look in network at console, it gives the following message:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/api.html/delete/AF
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 405 
Remote Address: [::1]:8888
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

My java code looks like this:

```
@Path("/api.html")
public class WorldService {
     private CountryPostgresDaoImpl CountryPostgresDao = new CountryPostgresDaoImpl();

@Path("/delete/{code}")
@DELETE
@Produces("application/json")
public Response deleteCountry(@PathParam("code") String code) throws SQLException {
    Country country = getCountryByCode(code);
    if(!CountryPostgresDao.Delete(country)) {
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }
    return Response.ok().build();

}
```

And the client side looks like this:

```
    $("body").on('click', '#delete', function(){
         var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
         console.log(trid);
         $.ajax({
             url: '/api.html/delete/' + trid,
             type: 'DELETE',
             success: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
             }
         });
     });
```

Comment: @mplungjan Unfortunately not

Comment: Sure your latest code is the one running? Or are you sure you're having the correct import for `@DELETE`?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Jep this is the one running for sure! Use the following import: import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;

Comment: Does your application not have a **context root** or is it exposed at `/`? Don't you have a fragment of the path on your `jax-rs` application class? It's odd that your resource class is exposed directly under `/`. And this error could be caused be the wrong path being hit.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Not completely sure, The full link of the api.html is http://localhost:8888/firstapp/api.html and the link http://localhost:8888/firstapp/api.html/delete/AF should be the one deleting. i've also tried changing the url in AJAX to firstapp/api.html/delete/ but this returns the same error

Comment: @WesleyvanStraalen As you can see in your logs, your jquery is calling `http://localhost:8888/api.html/delete/AF`. The application context path is missing...

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I've changed it now and the jquery is calling http://localhost:8888/firstapp/api.html/delete/AF but still returns the same error. Perhaps something in my java paths?

Comment: Are you sure the port is 8888 and not 8080?

Comment: @IkerObregonReigosa yes definetly

Comment: I do not know in what framework are you doing that, but in Spring you need to mark the class with @Controller to ensure that is a Controller.

Comment: @IkerObregonReigosa I am not using any framework, it's a school assignment

Comment: What browser are you using to test your application?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the initial slash as in the following snippet

```
@Path("delete/{code}")
@DELETE
```